# Shared Preference not saving exact instance state of android App

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple Click Counter Android App using Java.  I am new to Java. I'm Trying to save the number of the count upon exit of the application, whether if the back button is pressed or the app is closed or crashes, etc. Here is my code so far:

```
public class wazeefa extends Activity  {

//Count Button  
TextView txtCount;
Button btnCount;
int count; 
Button wmute;
Button wreset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);

    //SAVE COUNT
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    count = app_preferences.getInt("count", 0);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount);
    txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("count", ++count);
    editor.commit();

    //Button SOUND AND COUNT
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bubble);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount); 
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wclick);   

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View V) {
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
           count++; 
           if (count > 50) count = 0; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           if (count > 0) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           if (count > 9) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zikrimage); 
           if (count > 39) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
           mpButtonClick.start(); 

    //RESET Button
    wreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wreset);       
    wreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            count = 0; 
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);;
               txtCount.setText("0");


    }
```

I'm having 2 issues with the app.

Firstly the count is not being saved to what it is when the application is closed and then opened again.  For example if the count is at '20' and I hit the back button, then go back to the same page the count will display as '3'. - The funny thing is, that every time I have tried the above and gone back into the application after hitting the back button the count has gone up by 1 count.

The second issue is that when I go back into the app and the count shows as '5' just for example, the Reset button no longer functions - it does nothing.  But when I continue the count and then hit the Reset button it changes the count to zero again.

Please can anyone assist in fixing the above 2 issues?

New Code after suggestions:

```
public class wazeefa extends Activity  {

//Count Button  
TextView txtCount;
Button btnCount;
Button wmute;
Button wreset;
public static int count=0;
SharedPreferences app_preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);

    //SAVE COUNT
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    count = app_preferences.getInt("count", 0);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount);
    txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");}

protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

    // save count value here
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
   editor.putInt("count", count);
   editor.commit();

    //SOUND and COUNT
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bubble);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount); 
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wclick);   

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View V) {
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
           count++; 
           if (count > 50) count = 0; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           if (count > 0) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           if (count > 9) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zikrimage); 
           if (count > 39) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
           txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
           mpButtonClick.start(); 

    //RESET Button
    wreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wreset);       
    wreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            count = 0; 
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);;
               txtCount.setText("0");


    }
```

Final part of my code:

```
 protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();

    // save count value here

      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
      editor.putInt("count", count);
      editor.commit();


         };
     });
      }});
  };}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare count as static at class level :

```
public static int count=0;
SharedPreferences app_preferences ;
```

and use `onPause` for saving count value in  `SharedPreferences` as :

```
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

    // save count value here
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
   editor.putInt("count", count);
   editor.commit();
 }
```

Comment: If I want to save the count when the back button is pressed, would I also need to use onDestroy?

Comment: @Mustafa : it is better to user onPause()  instead of  onDestroy() or button click because if you save value in  onPause()  then it will save every time when user press Home Button or Back button. and on Button click you just need to update count value it will auto inserted latest in SharedPreferences because of Count is static

Comment: I have changed the code as suggested, but where the count is usually displayed I am now getting the message 'This app has been...'.  The count is no longer displayed.

Comment: @Mustafa : try as  by changing `app_preferences = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` to `app_preferences = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Hi thanks so much for that.  I have copied and pasted the code, howeve I'm getting following error 'Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody' tried all sorts but can't get rid of it...

Comment: OK, i think I have fixed the above problem but now I get a further error: 'The method onPause() is undefined for the type Object'.  See the final part of my code above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21649/discussion-between-mustafa-and--k)

Comment: OK the data is now being saved.  Thanks Prosper for your detailed answers and help, wouldn't have been even close to the answer without your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be saved at exit, post this code in onDestroy() instead of onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", ++count);
editor.commit();
```